# Add text from api into Editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm using LineControl Editor in my app. Everything works fine, except when i try to add text into the editor.

This is the link to the github of LineControl: https://github.com/suyati/line-control/wiki

If i follow the instructions, it looks very easy to add text, except when the text comes from an api. This is my code so far:

```
function detailOfProduct(){
    $http.get('/theApi')
    .then(function(data){
        $scope.detailList = data.data.Response;
    });
}
```

The response it's something like this:

```
{Id: 1, Name: "Chuck", Description: "Hi, this is a description of me"}
```

To activate the text editor i'm using this part of the code:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
        $("#txtDescription").Editor();
    });
```

And to set the text:

```
  $("#txtDescription").Editor("setText", "Here goes your text");
```

What can i do if i need to add the text of Description of the api response on the part of "Here goes your text"?

I'm using AngularJs, Javascript and a little of JQuery.

Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to do this:

```
function detailOfProduct(){
    $http.get('/theApi')
    .then(function(data){
        $scope.detailList = data.data.Response;
        $("#txtDescription").Editor("setText", data.data.Response.Description);
    });
}
```

Just don't try to use any AngularJS 2-way data binding in conjunction with this library (or with jQuery) or it could lead to some tough to fix bugs.